# How iText determine if a resource is already present in the pdf file?

Tags: java, itext

How iText determine if a resource is already present in the pdf file ?
What's the algorithm ? hash MD5/SHA-1 ? I tried to find it in the source of rel 5.5.9 [here](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases) without success :(

Comment: In which context? IText does not always check for excusing identical resources...

Comment: You'll have to clarify. Are you creating PDF? Are you manipulating PDF? Which resource are you talking about? Are you referring to `PdfSmartCopy`? (If so, we indeed work with a hash?) Are you referring to `Image`? (If so, we work on the level of the Java object. Creating two different `Image` objects from the same image source = redundant image bytes.) Please don't let us guess what your question is about. Be more specific!